# Access ref of a redux connected component

Tags: react-redux

I used to have a component like this:

```
class BlahDumb extends Component {
   toggleMe = () => console.log('toggling')
   render() {
      ...
   }
}
```

I would then use it like this:

```
class App extends Component {
    doIt = () => this.el.toggleMe()
    refEl = el => this.el = el;
    render() {
       return (
          <div>
              <BlahDumb ref={this.refEl} />
              <button onClick={this.doIt} />
          </div>
       )
    }
}
```

Now this worked well UNTIL I connected Blah it to redux.

I changed Blah to this:

```
const Blah = connect(function() { ... })(BlahDumb);
```

Now I can no longer access `toggleMe` from `this.el` that I got via ref. Is this bad pattern? Or is there a way to get a childs refs?

Comment: What is suspect is that you probably did not export the component properly. Try `export default connect(function() {})(BlahDumb)`

Answer (score 4):

Connect your child component passing options argument to connect like

```
const Blah = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
    null,
    { withRef: true }
)(BlahDumb)
```

And in your parent component call the method in child using `getWrappedInstance()` function like.

```
this.el.getWrappedInstance().toggleMe()
```